# Difference between Azure AD and Azure AD B2C tokens

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have been working on Azure AD Authorization code flow all these days and suddenly started moving everything to Azure AD B2C and I came across lot of differences between Azure AD and Azure AD B2C. Can Someone answer my questions below.

1. In Azure AD when we register a Native App, it allows http or https as redirect urls. Azure AD B2C doesn't support this (Since both follow OAUTH specs both should behave similarly)
2. Azure AD JWT access tokens has `x5c` entry where B2C doesn't have this entry. Any particular reason for this. I tried copying the public keys from Azure AD and tried to upload the same signing keys to B2C but this didn't work. Not sure what I was missing but my question is why these access tokens differ in their signature.

Comment: You can't upload Azure AD's signing keys to B2C because what you can see are the public keys. You need the private keys to do signing with them. If the signatures are different, then the signing keys are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first issue, I suggest that you rise a feedback [from](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c) here if you require this feature.

And for the second issue, it is same to verify the tokens from Azure AD B2C and normal Azure AD. We can generate the public key using the exponent(`e`) and modulus(`n`). **But the keys endpoint is different, we need to using the link like below to retrieve the keys for the Azure AD B2C**:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/discovery/v2.0/keys?p={signInPolicy}
```

Here is the code to verify the token issued by Azure AD B2C for your reference:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{          
    var idtoken = "";

    var exponent = "AQAB";
    var modulus = "";
    var result=  VerifyTokenDetails(idtoken, exponent, modulus);
}
private static bool VerifyTokenDetails(string idToken, string exponent, string modulus)
{
    try
    {              
        var parts = idToken.Split('.');
        var header = parts[0];
        var payload = parts[1];
        string signedSignature = parts[2];
        //Extract user info from payload   
        string userInfo = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Base64UrlDecode(payload));
        //Which will be Verified
        string originalMessage = string.Concat(header, ".", payload);
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64UrlDecode(modulus);
        string keyBase = Convert.ToBase64String(keyBytes);
        string key = @"<RSAKeyValue> <Modulus>" + keyBase + "</Modulus> <Exponent>" + exponent + "</Exponent> </RSAKeyValue>";
        bool result = VerifyData(originalMessage, signedSignature, key);
        if (result)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
    return false;
}

/// <summary>  
/// Verifies encrypted signed message with public key encrypted original message.  
/// </summary>  
/// <param name="originalMessage">Original message as string. (Encrypted form)</param>  
/// <param name="signedMessage">Signed message as string. (Encrypted form)</param>  
/// <param name="publicKey">Public key as XML string.</param>  
/// <returns>Boolean True if successful otherwise return false.</returns>  
private static bool VerifyData(string originalMessage, string signedMessage, string publicKey)
{
    bool success = false;
    using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bytesToVerify = encoder.GetBytes(originalMessage);
        byte[] signedBytes = Base64UrlDecode(signedMessage);
        try
        {

            rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
            SHA256Managed Hash = new SHA256Managed();
            byte[] hashedData = Hash.ComputeHash(signedBytes);
            // Summary:
            //     Verifies that a digital signature is valid by determining the hash value in the
            //     signature using the provided public key and comparing it to the hash value of
            //     the provided data.
            success = rsa.VerifyData(bytesToVerify, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), signedBytes);
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            success = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        }
    }
    return success;
}

private static byte[] Base64UrlDecode(string input)
{
    var output = input;
    output = output.Replace('-', '+'); // 62nd char of encoding  
    output = output.Replace('_', '/'); // 63rd char of encoding  
    switch (output.Length % 4) // Pad with trailing '='s  
    {
        case 0: break; // No pad chars in this case  
        case 2: output += "=="; break; // Two pad chars  
        case 3: output += "="; break; // One pad char  
        default: throw new System.Exception("Illegal base64url string!");
    }
    var converted = Convert.FromBase64String(output); // Standard base64 decoder  
    return converted;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am also using similar approach to generate public key. https://play.golang.org/p/7wWMBOp10R . Wondering if there is any reason for the difference of tokens between Azure AD and B2C?

Comment: Did the token verifying issue was fixed? AFAIK, there is no `x5c` claim in the token issued by Azure AD(refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims)).

Comment: I was able to somehow figure out using the golang library. I have to convert this to lua because the token is validated by the server which in our case is nginx running some lua libraries.The example states that Azure AD token contains this header, which means it will have x5c entry. I have worked through various scenarios and noticed the difference in tokens `{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "kriMPdmBvx68skT8-mPAB3BseeA"
}`

Comment: @VenkateshMarepalli AFAIK, there is no need to use `x5c` in the progress of token validation. We just use the `x5t` claim to identify the public key from keys endpoint. Then we can create keys using the value of `e` and `n` to generate the public key to verify the token. More detail about the verifying the token from Azure AD B2C please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tokens#token-validation).

Comment: I guess this will make my question more clear. I should have asked you about the jwks end points. Why the public keys from B2C and AD differ. Azure AD keys have `x5c` entry B2C doesn't have.

Comment: I should have asked you about the jwks end points not the token, I have a token validation method which stopped working when we moved to B2C then I realized the public key entries differ. Why the public keys from B2C and AD differ. Azure AD has `x5c` entry B2C doesn't. Sample from AD B2C `{
"kid":"t8zPAboFkCJ9b-n....Ao",
"nbf":1490400391,
"use":"sig",
"kty":"RSA",
"e":"AQAB",
"n":"0zUbvER2.."
}` AD Key `{
"kty":"RSA",
"use":"sig",
"kid":"1LTMzakihiRla..",
"x5t":"1LTMzakihiRla..",
"n":"3sKccHw..",
"e":"AQAB",
"x5c":[
"MIIDYDCCAkig.."
],
"issuer":"https://login..com/../v2.0"
}`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Honestly, I don't know the real reason about why there is no `x5c` entry in the jwks endpoints for Azure AD B2C jwks endpoint. However to verify the token issued from Azure AD B2C, we are not required to use the `x5c`. As the code in the post, it generate the public key from the value of `e` and `n`. You may check the library to see whether it use these two values correctly. More detail about Azure AD B2C token validation, you can refer [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tokens#token-validation)

Comment: After the further investigation, it seems we can generate the public key both using `x5c` or (exponent and modulus). To verity the tokens issued from Azure AD B2C, please using the exponent and modulus.

Comment: Thank you. I have posted feedback about the redirect uri and thanks for the code.