# Azure AD jwks uri configuration

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory

I cannot find configuration where I could change jwks_uri body. I saw that Azure B2C jwks_uri returns jwks with or without x5c entry. Is it possible to configure Azure AD to returns wks without x5c array?

Comment: Please let us know the reason why do you want to change jwks URL body?

Comment: Yes, reasoning would be good be as you are most likely doing something you shouldn't be doing. And no, there is no way to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate is in the jwks_uri content regardless. x5c is just the cert chain it's just the same as the n and e values but encoded differently. What are you trying to accomplish by requesting to do this? also no it is not possible.

If you are trying to validate, you should be using the modulus and exponent values anyway e and n. here's a good piece of code for doing that. [Difference between Azure AD and Azure AD B2C tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664510/difference-between-azure-ad-and-azure-ad-b2c-tokens) in the comments there is a good deal of links that detail the process.